# Flutter need to call clean and pub get everytime before build_runner

Tags: flutter, dart, build-runner

I am using the [localize_it](https://pub.dev/packages/localize_it) package for localization which uses the `build_runner` to create some code.

The problem/inconvenience is that I always have to run

> `flutter clean`
>
> `flutter pub get`

before calling

> `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

Is there any way I can avoid this? Or can I combing these calls so I can simply call something like `flutter localize_it` that does everything for me?

Comment: try adding model by own without using build_runner

Comment: @Kokila what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to advice https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization instead of localize_it. It is much more convenient and easy to use.

Comment: I prefer localize_it since for me it is actually more convenient and easy to use. It does everything for you

Comment: Have you even tried easy_localization?

Comment: yes :) have you ever tried `localize_it`? :D

Comment: no. Because easy_localization didn't make any problem for me that I need to ask from stackoverflow community. It works as it should:)